# JSHint warning about closures inside loops using outer variables

Tags: javascript, loops, closures, jshint

My code does work but I don't want the jshint errors anymore:

> Functions declared within loop referencing an outer scoped variable may lead to confusing semantics

1. I've tried using let from ES6 to get around the error because I thought that would solve the problem. I configured my gruntfile to use ES6 as well.
2. I tried using two loops, the outer loop with variable 'i' and the inner loop with variable 'j'

Neither worked.

Full code provided here:  https://jsfiddle.net/rwschmitz/zz7ot3uu/

```
var hobbies = document.getElementsByClassName("hobbies");
var active = false;

// For mouse input

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hobbies[i].onmouseover = function() {
            hobbies[0].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
            hobbies[1].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
            hobbies[2].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
            hobbies[3].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
            hobbies[4].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
    };
}

// For click input

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    hobbies[i].onclick = function() {
            hobbies[0].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
            hobbies[1].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
            hobbies[2].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
            hobbies[3].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
            hobbies[4].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your loops to something like this, using `Array#forEach()`:

```
var hobbies = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('hobbies'));
var classes = ['hobbies-slide-left', 'hobbies-slide-right'];
var events = ['mouseover', 'click'];

function addHobbyClass (hobby, index) {
  hobby.classList.add(this[index % this.length]);
}

function hobbyEventListener () {
  hobbies.forEach(addHobbyClass, classes);
}

hobbies.forEach(function (hobby) {
  this.forEach(function (event) {
    this.addEventListener(event, hobbyEventListener);
  }, hobby);
}, events);
```

Comment: Yep, that works.  I had to add 7 semicolons where appropriate.  I'm a bit new to StackOverflow.  So I'm not sure if that's worth editing your answer or not.  Regardless, the code does still work with your solution and gets rid of the errors.  I'll mark as accepted.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I use a different linter called `standard`. It's not _actually_ a standard, per se, but it embraces JavaScript's ASI rule (automatic semicolon insertion). Since this question is specifically about linting, I can add them back if you prefer.

Comment: I'd say add them back in strictly because it's on topic w/ JSHint.  Either way that's awesome you answered so quickly and I truly appreciate it man!

Comment: @rudolphschmitz done, good luck with standardizing your project's code, that's a great practice.

Answer (score 1):

Two additional examples of how to fix the problem.

```js
var hobbies = document.querySelectorAll('.hobbies');
var eventHooks = ['mouseover', 'click'];

hobbies.forEach(function(hobby) {
  eventHooks.forEach(function(hook) {
    hobby.addEventListener(hook, function() {
      hobbies[0].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
      hobbies[1].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
      hobbies[2].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
      hobbies[3].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
      hobbies[4].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
    });
  });
});
```

```js
var hobbies = document.getElementsByClassName('hobbies');
var eventHooks = ['mouseover', 'click'];

// Attach events
var attachEvents = function(key) {
  eventHooks.forEach(function(hook) {
    hobbies[key].addEventListener(hook, function() {
      hobbies[0].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
      hobbies[1].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
      hobbies[2].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
      hobbies[3].classList.add('hobbies-slide-right');
      hobbies[4].classList.add('hobbies-slide-left');
    });
  });
};

// Init
var init = function() {
  // Loop through hobbies
  for (var i = 0; i < hobbies.length; i++) {
    attachEvents(i);
  }   
}

init();
```

Comment: Since this is about linting, I would also try addressing the issue with non-DRY code (the `hobbies[hardcodedNumberLiteral].classList.add(hardcodedString)`), similar to how you addressed the `eventHooks`. I'd actually like to include that in my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts yes! adding classes is a lot cleaner in your example.

Comment: Thank you for providing multiple solutions!  Looks like I need to become more familiar with the forEach method.